# Potential which doesn't vanish at infinity

Tags: electrostatics, potential, vectors

Consider the electric field $E=\frac{e_r}{r}$ on space with the origin removed. A calculation yields $E=-\nabla \log(r),$ so this is the potential. But shouldn't a potential always be choosable such that it vanishes at infinity? Surely there is no additive constant such that $log$ vanishes at infinity. What's going on here? For field with $E= \frac{e_r}{r^n},$ $n \geq2$ it works, why not here? This electric field is quite physical, as it represents the field of a cylinder contracted to the origin.

Comment: E proportional to 1/r requires a very long cylinder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no requirement that potentials must be zero at infinity, nor is there a requirement that we need to be able to achieve zero by a gauge transformation. When the potential does not have a finite value at spatial infinity, this just means you cannot turn a bound state of the potential into a free state by endowing it with a finite amount of energy. Your charged wire extends to infinity and hence you have "charges at infinity", while our usual idea of why potentials should be zero at infinity is precisely because real systems are bounded in space and hence we are infinitely far from their charges at infinity.

Note also that the potential $\log(r)$ is dimensionally inconsistent, and that you need to introduce a length scale $\Lambda$ and a linear charge density $\lambda$ to express the potential correctly as 
$$ \lambda \log(\Lambda / r).$$

For finite charged wires, an extra term appears and $\Lambda$ is naturally identified with the finite length of the wire.